# "Oldest Surviving" or "Earliest Surviving"

Tags: phrases

When describing an object, should you use "oldest surviving" or "earliest surviving"?

Comment: [***earliest** surviving manuscript*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=earliest+surviving+manuscript%2Coldest+surviving+manuscript&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cearliest%20surviving%20manuscript%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coldest%20surviving%20manuscript%3B%2Cc0) is significantly more common - at least for *that* particular "object". But you'd rarely encounter ***earliest surviving brother***, for example. With *people*, it's usually ***oldest***.

Comment: Welcome to SE EL&L. I think yours is good question and appropriate to the site.

Comment: ...but others would like it expanded. I don't think the question can be answered with "commonly available references" as it as a phrase. Nor is it appropriate to ELL. Perhaps reference to examples of the interchangable usage found using a Google search might fit the bill.

Answer (score 1):

As regards *objects* (which was the subject of the question), both are used, and, thus, both can be used. However I would suggest that the *best* use will be governed by the writer’s intention, reflecting the psychological difference the roots of the two words will have on the reader — ‘old’ reflecting age, and ‘early’ reflecting time.

Thus, although examples of both [‘oldest surviving manuscript’](https://www.reddit.com/r/hinduism/comments/2qf5md/what_is_the_oldest_surviving_manuscript_of_the/) and [‘earliest surviving manuscript’](http://www.historyofinformation.com/expanded.php?id=1702) are found, whether intended or not, the former implies *concern with the age of the manuscript*, e.g.

> “…the **oldest** surviving manuscript (over a thousand years old!).”

whereas the latter implies *concern with the date it was written*, e.g.

> “…the **earliest** surviving manuscript (dating from 34BC).”

(my own contrived examples)

To reiterate, it is a question of style and clarity of communication, rather than one of ‘right and wrong’.

**Footnote — People**

Although the question is about objects, as one of the comments remarks, ‘oldest’ is normally used for people. In a previous version of my answer I wrote ‘always’, but an internet search proved me wrong, turning up an instance where ‘earliest’ is required. Consider the case of a multiple birth (e.g. quintuplets) in which three babies survive. They will have been born at different times, so one could refer to:

> “the oldest surviving quin”

However, in discussing the general question of premature birth one might wish to refer to the earliest time in gestation that a baby has been born and survived. This would be:

> [“the earliest surviving premature baby”](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/health/article-1380282/Earliest-surviving-premature-baby-goes-home-parents.html)

who, incidentally, would be the *youngest* to survive.

Comment: That sounds right to me but can you cite this answer?

Comment: @librariman — actually it wasn't right. Thanks for making me do some work. I think my revised answer has sufficient citation, although the main argument is based on logic in relation to the meaning of the words old and early, which I don't think need a dictiionary citation to justify.